# Write output of R loop to output file or indicate progress?

Tags: r, loops, save, output, progress-bar

I'm running quite a complex loop in R that takes ~ 20-30 days to run. The details of the loop might not be too relevant (it's the Viterbi algorithm to decode the most likely state sequence for post-processing the output of a hidden Markov model). So far, once it has been successively going through all the loops, I was writing the results to a data file.

```
saveRDS(z_star, file = "z_star.Rda")
```

However, this is quite frustrating, as I cannot see how far the loops have already made it and I fear that in the end something could happen that ruins all the computation progress (e.g., the resulting data frame could be larger than the RAM of the server I'm using).

My question is if I should rather 1) write to an output file with every loop, or 2) implement some kind of progress tracking. For both options I have no concrete idea on how to implement it and would therefore be very grateful for code.

```
N_draws = 2000
N = 100000
z_star = matrix(nrow = N_draws, ncol = N)
best_logp = data.frame(matrix(nrow = N, ncol = S))
back_ptr = best_logp


for(d in 1:N_draws){
  for (k in 1:K)
    best_logp[1, k] = dnorm(y[1],
                            mean = mu[k],
                            sd = sigma_q[d],
                            log = TRUE)
  for (t in 2:N) {
    for (k in 1:K) {
      best_logp[t, k] = -Inf
      for (j in 1:K) {
        real logp;
        logp = best_logp[t-1, j] + log(theta[j, k]) + dnorm(y[t],
                                                            mean = mu[k],
                                                            sd = sigma_q[d],
                                                            log = TRUE)
        if (logp > best_logp[t, k]) {
          back_ptr[t, k] = j;
          best_logp[t, k] = logp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  log_p_z_star = max(best_logp[N]);
  for (k in 1:K)
    if (best_logp[N, k] == log_p_z_star)
      z_star[N] = k;
  for (t in 1:(N - 1))
    z_star[N - t] = back_ptr[N - t + 1, z_star[N - t + 1]];
}
```

Comment: Adding progress indicators seems sensible.  Nothing worse than waiting and not knowing if it's failed or still processing.  Options include the "progress" package for shorter cycle times, but with days, how about pushing a message, such as using "pocketapi"?

Comment: Two more thoughts, if you can store the intermediate files, such as from the `K in 1:K` loop, then you might be able to skip some processing if it fails or in the next run.  Finally if you can *functionalise* your code, it may offer performance, stability and speed advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thoughts, I decided to do something simple:

I used the index and the system time to indicate the progress using

```
for(d in 1:N_draws){
  old <- Sys.time()
  cat(c("draw", d, "out of", N_draws, "\n"))
```

and before the last bracket closes

```
  new = Sys.time() - old
  cat(c("time for draw", d, ":", new, "seconds", "\n"))
  percentage_completed = d/N_draws * 100
  cat(c("percentage completed:", percentage_completed, "percent", "\n"))
    }
```

returning

```
draw 1 out of 2000 
time for draw 1 : 0.839755058288574 seconds 
percentage completed: 0.05 percent 
draw 2 out of 2000 
time for draw 2 : 0.735047101974487 seconds 
percentage completed: 0.1 percent 
draw 3 out of 2000
```